# C++ / how to return best time result?

Tags: c++

In the `TimeResult` class i want to display the best time result.

Lets say I have several time results. and want to return the lowest one.

Header:

```
class TimeResult : public SportData
{
    double time;
public:
    TimeResult(string _discipline,string _name,double _time);
    virtual ~TimeResult();
    virtual double getBestResult();
};
```

Source:

```
double TimeResult::getBestResult()
{
    ???????
}
```

Comment: `return time;` As far as I can tell, you only have one result - it must necessarily be the best one.

Comment: how can I get more than one result? should I use " list " ?

Comment: I do not know enough about the problem you are trying to solve to be able to provide design advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use static member for best time and static function for accessing this member variable. Member variable should be updated every time you add better time.
(It should be usefull to have another static variable, just for knowing if you already set the bestTime variable - relavant for correct updating of bestTime variable)

Code example (header):

```
class TimeResult : public SportData {
    double time;
    static double bestTime;
    static bool bestTimeWasSet;
public:
    TimeResult(string _discipline, string _name, double _time);
    virtual ~TimeResult();
    static double getBestResult();
};
```

Code example (cpp):

```
double TimeResult::getBestResult() {
    return TimeResult::bestTime;
}
```